# Sql query for password column

Tags: mysql

What data type to set for a password field in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

varchar should be set as password field type in mysql. It accepts characters as well as numbers.And it has variable length. This is used commonly.

Comment: But never even think of storing the password in cleartext. varchar may be used to store the Base64-encoded password-hash.

Comment: Yes. Its just about the data field. Where ever the password should be saved. It should be encrypted.